# fade in fade out with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to open a div when hovering on an a tag. I can do it with css, but I want to apply fade in and fade out to that div. I can't do it.

```
<a href="#">
   <img src="img/detayaltresim1.jpg" alt="">
   <div></div>
</a>


div{
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 80px;
    background: #000;
    bottom: 46px;
    left: -78px;
    z-index: 2;
    display:block;
}
a{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
a:hover div {
    display:block;
}
```

and my a tag has parent. I can't do it with j-query. Why?

```
<script>
            $('urundetayisagteknik2 a').mouseover(function(){
            //show the box
            $(this).children('.urundetayisagteknik2 a div').stop().animate({opacity:1},300);
            });

            $('urundetayisagteknik2 a').mouseleave(function(){
             //hide the box
            $(this).children('.urundetayisagteknik2 a div').stop().animate({opacity:0},500);
            });
</script>
```

Comment: You're targeting the `$('urundetayisagteknik2 a')` wrong. Should be `$('.urundetayisagteknik2 a')`. Or is this a typo in the question?

Comment: please provide the complete html where is the `urundetayisagteknik2 ` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class name in jquery having no `.` May be that is the mistake.
Edit that like

```
$('.urundetayisagteknik2 a').mouseover(function(){
  //show the box
  $(this).children('.urundetayisagteknik2 a div').stop().animate({opacity:1},300);
});
```

**OR** you can try the following one

**CSS**

```
<style>
div{
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 80px;
    background: #000;
    top: 46px;
    left: 20px;
    z-index: 2;
    display:none;
}
a{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<a class="link" href="#">
   Link
   <div></div>
</a>
```

**JQuery**

```
<script>
$('.link').mouseover(function(){
    $('.link div').fadeIn();
});

$('.link').mouseleave(function(){
    $('.link div').fadeOut();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var a = $('.urundetayisagteknik2 a');
var div = a.find('div');

a.on({
    mouseover: function () {
        div.stop().animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 300);
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        div.stop().animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 300);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try the below script

```
        $( ".urundetayisagteknik2 a" ).hover(function() {
                $( this ).find( "div" ).stop( true, true ).fadeIn();
        }, function() {
                $( this ).find( "div" ).stop( true, true ).fadeOut();
        });
```

jQuery's hover() function can be used for this. The first function is called when mouseenter is fired and the second is called when mouseleave is fired. see the [API](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution by jQuery.

**HTML.**

```
<a href="#">
   This is a anchor tag
   <div class="dropDown">hidden div</div>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.dropDown { display:none;}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('a').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).find('.dropDown').fadeIn();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).find('.dropDown').fadeOut();
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QfkgA/)

Answer (score 0):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/cX88R/)**

**css**

```
#test {
    margin: 1.5em auto;
    width: 10em;
    height: 10em;
    background: gray;
}
```

**js**

```
var test = $('#test'),
    $in = $('#in'),
    out = $('#out'),
    toggle = $('#toggle'),
    to = $('#to');


$in.click(function() {
    test.fadeIn(1000, function() {
        alert('Complete');
    });
});


out.click(function() {
    test.fadeOut(1000, function() {
        alert('Complete');
    });
});


toggle.click(function() {
    test.fadeToggle(1000, function() {
        alert('Complete');
    });
});

to.click(function() {
    test.fadeTo(1000, 0.5, function() {
        alert('Complete');
    });
});
```